# How to continuously remove outliers from a vector when calculating an exponentially weighted moving average in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am using MATLAB R2020a on a MacOS. I am calculating an exponentially weighted moving mean using the dsp.MovingAverage function and am trying to remove vector elements in real-time based on 2 conditions -  if the new element causes the mean to exceed 1.5 times the 'overall' mean so far, or if it is below 0.5 times the 'overall' mean so far.

In other words,the weighted mean with the current element is compared to the previous weighted mean, and if the current element causes the weighted mean to increase above 1.5 times the previous mean or go below 0.5 times the previous mean, then it should be ignored and the recursive equation is instead applied to the next element, and so on. In the end, I'd like to have a vector containing the outliers removed.

This is the function I am using to calculate the exponentially weighted moving mean:

```
movavgExp = dsp.MovingAverage('Method', 'Exponential weighting', 'ForgettingFactor', 0.4);
mean_cycle_period_exp = movavgExp(cycle_periods);
```

I tried doing this by creating a for loop which manipulates the algorithm used by the dsp.MovingAverage function as outlined here:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.movingaverage-system-object.html

However, this manual method of finding the weighted mean produces a different graphical output to the function.

```
% Create a vector containing 60 cycle periods with a step increase by 0.002 seconds 
cycle_period_step_change = [0.7:0.002:0.82]; 

% Calculate weights manually 
lambda = 0.1;
w = zeros(length(cycle_period_step_change),1); 
w(1) = 1; % initialize the weight for the first sample
for i = 2:length(cycle_period_step_change)
    w(i) = lambda*w(i-1) + 1; % calculate the successive weights
end

% Calculate moving mean with weights manually
x = zeros(length(cycle_period_step_change), 1);
x(1) = 2;
for i = 2:length(cycle_period_step_change)
    x(i) = (1 - 1/w(i))*x(i - 1) + (1/w(i))*x(i);
end
```

[This is output when I manually calculate the weighted mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiDJh.png)
[This is the output when I use the function to calculate the weighted mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by4Jf.png)

Furthermore, when I implement a for loop to exclude outliers from the moving mean in real-time, it produces an error:

```
% Calculate moving mean with weights manually
x = zeros(length(cycle_period_step_change), 1);
x(1) = 2;
for i = 2:length(cycle_period_step_change)
    x(i) = (1 - 1/w(i))*x(i - 1) + (1/w(i))*x(i);
      if x(i) > 1.5*(1 - 1/w(i - 1))*x(i - 2) + (1/w(i - 1))*x(i - 1)
        x(i) = [];
      elseif x(i) < 0.5*(1 - 1/w(i - 1))*x(i - 2) + (1/w(i - 1))*x(i - 1)
        x(i) = [];
      end
end
```

I would very much appreciate any suggestions on how to tackle this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself in a simple loop? Seems like you could do that to at least create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, I have now provided further clarity on my attempt so far, thanks!